# Azure Devops pipeline is not picking latest visual studio version

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

'Visual studio build solution task' in the Azure pipeline has latest visual studio version selected. However from the console log I can find it is not selecting the latest version (2022) instead it is selecting the 2017 version.

Even in the console log of my previous task (Nuget restore) I can see it is picking only the 2017 version.

Is there a way that I change the solution to Visual studio version 2019.

**Note**: Main reason I want to use 2019 version is because current version of my MSBuild is not compatible with VS version 2017. Because of this my pipeline is failing.

Is there a way I can change the VS version in Azure Devops pipeline. Can someone guide me please?

Comment: If you are using Microsoft-hosted agent windows-latest or windows-2022, with your task, it will use VS2022 by default. If you'd like to use VS2019, change the agent to "Windows-2019".

Comment: A minimal example of your pipeline would be great.

Answer (score 3):

```
Is there a way I can change the VS version in Azure Devops pipeline?
```

You can use a **MSBUILD task** and switch from **Version** to **Specify Location** and insert the path to the **msbuild.exe of VS2022**.

**Ex:**
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe`.

Look at the screenshot below:  [image]

**Note**: Please make sure your path is correct in the MSBuild.exe task.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing a basic pipeline yml file (maybe you are using classic instead of yml?), we can only guess.
Is there a possibility that the NuGetCommand task is finding a solution file in your repo that references the 2017 version of VS?
NuGetCommand will "restore" (install) the version it finds unless something else overrides.